# Requirejs and load multiple libraries in module

Tags: javascript, requirejs, amd

How can I load multiple amd libraries  in requirejs. For example, I've many modules, having below code:

```
define(["jquery", "backbone", "underscore", "handlebars"], 
    function ($, Backbone, _, Handlebars) {
        ...
        // code
        ...
})
```

How i can load all necessary libraries in module easier(may be as a single library)?

Comment: I guess you need to define all modules in every module you want to use them

Comment: You can't load it any easier than what you posted. Even if you manage to hack it, it will go against the proper use of modular design. Before you code something, you list what the code depends on. If you were to create some code that loads all dependencies "magically" - that's a bit of a cabbage code. Basically, you don't really have a problem. This is how it's done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not really in the requirejs philosophy, but you can make a module including the library and put them into an object like this :

```
// myModule.js
define(["jquery", "backbone", "underscore", "handlebars"], function ($, Backbone, _, Handlebars) {
    return {
        $ : $,
        Backbone : Backbone,
        _ : _,
        Handlebars : Handlebars
    };
});

// Into an other file
define(['myModule'], function(myModule) {
    myModule.Backbone.Model({ ... });
});
```